# Filtering out time data from R data frame

Tags: r

So i have a dataset in R:

```
IncidentID         Time           Vehicle

 19002             4:48           Car
 19003             12:30          Motorcycle
 19004             14:00          Car
 19005             9:30           Bicycle
```

And I'm trying to **filter** out some data, since its quite a large dataset. The above is just a few examples of data.

I want to **filter out the data according to the time**, where say i want to obtain the data where the **Time** is between **12pm to 6pm** (18:00 in 24 hour format), hence i would have:

```
IncidentID         Time         Vehicle

 19003             12:30        Motorcycle
 19004             14:00        Car
```

I did:

```
incident <- read.csv("incident.csv")
afternoon_incident <- incident[which(incident$Time >= 12 && incident$Time <= 18),]
```

But I'm getting the error saying:

```
1: In Ops.factor(web$Time, 6:0) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(web$Time, 12:0) : ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first convert the `Time` into actual date-time object using `as.POSIXct` and then compare.

As you want to `subset` based on hour, we can extract only hour part of the data using `format` and keep rows which are in between 12 and 18 hour. Using base R, we can do

```
df$hour <- as.numeric(format(as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%H:%M"), "%H"))
subset(df, hour >= 12 & hour <= 18)

#  IncidentID  Time    Vehicle hour
#2      19003 12:30 Motorcycle   12
#3      19004 14:00        Car   14
```

You can remove the `hour` column later if not needed.

---

For a general solution, we can create a date-time column and then compare

```
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%H:%M")
subset(df, datetime >= as.POSIXct("12:30:00", format = "%T") & 
           datetime <= as.POSIXct("18:30:00", format = "%T"))
```

Comment: thanks. would this also work if i were to include the minutes factor, say 12:30 to 18:30?

Comment: @Maxxx not with the previous version. I update the answer for a general solution so that it will work for hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: if i were to introduce another column called Date, would it be df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format="%H:%M", df$Date, format="%m%d%y")?

Comment: because i noticed that the date time column will also have a date which is corresponding to the date today, but if i would want that date to correspond to the new date column, would it be so?

Comment: @Maxxx if you already have `Date` column you can `paste` them together by doing  `df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste0(df$Date, df$Time), format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")` assuming your `Date` column is of format `YYYY-mm-dd` and `Time` is in format `HH:MM`.

Comment: apparently the Date column follows the format such as 15/07/2009, where it begins with day, month and then year. would format=%d/%m%y do the trick?

Comment: the solution i suggested doesn't work, i seemed to be getting <NA> for all fields after including the date format.

Comment: interesting, after introducing the Date factor, the comparison of Time earlier between 12:30 and 18:30 couldn't be executed. Any idea on this?

Comment: @Maxxx mostly because `as.POSIXct("12:30:00", format = "%T")` has todays date. However, I am not 100% sure as I do not have your data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lubridate` to convert `Time` field into time object and then extract `hour` for filtering:

```
library(lubridate)
incident$Time <- hm(as.character(incident$Time))
incident[which(hour(incident$Time) >= 12 & hour(incident$Time) <= 18), ]
```